# Strange behavior of vertical-align in a td element

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

This bit of html renders like I want it to look ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7g9vjoap/5/)):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    thead th, td {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    X<br>Y
                </th>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

But I would like to move all CSS including the styling of the `td` element into one place like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7g9vjoap/6/)):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    thead th, td {
        text-align: center;
    }
    td {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    X<br>Y
                </th>
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

For a reason that I don't understand this breaks the vertical alignment of the glyphicon.

Can somebody explain why? And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can see with chrome developer tools that the bootstrap css is overriding your css. this is because it uses a higher priority/more specific css `selector` than what you are using.
(same way `id` supersedes `class`)

thats why it works when you use `inline style` but does not work when you specify it outside.

to make it work you can use:

```
td {
        vertical-align: middle !important;
    }
```

or if you dont want to use `!important` you can use a equivalent selector as bootstrap uses:

```
.table>tbody>tr>td{
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @gaurav5430, I have very little experience with CSS and this possibility didn't come to my mind!

Answer (score 3):

Default bootstrap styling here as you can see includes a sibling selector, thus it gets larger priority that your embedded styles. But inline styles get the more priority.

```
.table>tbody>tr>td {
padding: 8px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
vertical-align: top;
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

[image]

---

You can add `!important` (I will not recommend this)

or

continue using inline style

or

```
.table>tbody>tr>td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/7g9vjoap/8/)**